# How to test (pseudo)random sequence of bits with dieharder?

Tags: random

I'm thinking to perform the Dieharder tests for some number sequences. For now, my code is generating just ones and zeroes. In general, it will generate numbers between a and b.
How shall I format the input text for dieharder in order to test my sequence of ones and zeroes? Can I write like this

```
type: d
count: 100
numbit: 1
1
0
1
1
...
```

?

**Edit:** I figured out how to use Dieharder Suite on Linux and now I'm testing sequences of numbers with:

```
dieharder -f totest1M97.input -a
```

Where `totest1M97.input` is a simple text file with numbers as follows:

```
1
4
9
5
78
46
...
```

Still, wondering if the size of input is enough to feed Dieharder. I've read in the documentation that you can test a generator, such as `urandom` in Linux, with:

```
cat /dev/urandom | dieharder -a -g 200
```

How many numbers (input size) is enough for Dieharder to be happy?